# Integrate CSRMesh bluetooth with Google Home

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, actions-on-google, google-home, csr

I have a Google Home mini, and a CSRMesh bluetooth.
First, I need to pair my bluetooth device with google home, and after create a action for google assistant for light control for device.

I not have idea how start this project and if is possible, somewhere idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions do not run on the Google Home device itself, and Home devices do not directly manipulate most bluetooth smarthome devices. Instead, these devices rely on a cloud-based server, and the Assistant [communicates with this server](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) to control the devices.

Comment: Thanks, just that I thought. I will make a bridge for do it. Regards.

Comment: If the answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.